# Serilog in .NET 6 - Enrichers not working

Tags: serilog, .net-6.0

I am trying to use serilog in my .net 6 App and I am not able to get it working with enrichers. Below is my program.cs file:

```
using Serilog;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// remove default logging providers (clearing provides then no log appears)
//builder.Logging.ClearProviders();

// Serilog configuration        
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .Enrich.WithProperty("Property", "MyProperty")
    .CreateLogger();

// Register Serilog
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);

var app = builder.Build();


app.MapGet("/", (ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) => {
    var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("index");
    var position = new { Latitude = 25, Longitude = 134 };
    var elapsedMs = 34;
    logger.LogInformation("Processed {@Position} in {Elapsed:000} ms.", position, elapsedMs);
    return "Hello world";
});

app.Run();
```

if I Add "builder.Logging.ClearProviders()" then I cannot see any log message. When I remove "builder.Logging.ClearProviders()" I can see the logs but enrichers are not working.
This is happening in .Net 6 App only. Does anyone face the same issue with .net 6?
can anyone please help how to solve this issue ?

Comment: For Serilog, the display template needs to include `{Properties}` to show stuff you add via `Enrich.WithProperty`, i.e. you need to customize the template? I'd suggest going through the full walkthrough of the Add/ UseSerilog (I dont se you doing UseSerilog either). https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore

Comment: `builder.Host.UseSerilog()` is also a better bet than `builder.Logging.AddSerilog()`, for most uses.